# Re-using Total Commander's Viewer plugins in standalone applications outside TC - can it be done?

Tags: c#, total-commander

Is there a way to use plugins written for Total Commander in my own C# application?

I'm specifically interested in, for example, the viewer plugins e.g. ImgView, ArcView and CAD View.

Comment: Good question!  There are loads of very useful TC plugins, especially the viewers.  Might save quite a bit of time if the viewer itself is not the core competency of your application.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way how to use plugins originally written for Total Commander in your own C# application would certainly be the following:

See

http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=25751&sid=23d738091055d84ee97d12cef09b82a7

for a detailed description of all of the plugin functions which the host application (usually being the Total Commander program) can call after loading the plugi DLL. Notice that despite of their somewhat unusual file name extensions (.wlx or .wfx or .wcx etc.) these TC plugins are just ordinary DLLs (dynamic link libraries) which have simply been renamed accordingly.

An example of calling TC plugin functions from other programs is the UniversalViewer program available for downlod from the  www.uvviewsoft.com  web site.

Good luck!
Michael Diegelmann
(author of the TC lister plugin [ImgView](http://www.fh-rosenheim.de/~diegelmann/index_English.htm#ImgView))

Answer (score 2):

If you know an API why not? As long as Total Commander uses those plugins theoretically you should be able to do the same as well.

Here is a good example of [Writing a Total Commander plug-in in Visual Basic (or C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/ManagedTCPLugin.aspx)
So perhaps, after a deep investigation, you will be able to write your own plugin?